# Grid loadmask(true) is not working in gxt

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have to mask the GXT grid when the data is loading. I have set the loadmask parameter to be true in the grid component. But i am not able to see the masking. Do I need to add anything else beyond the below line?

```
grid.setLoadMask(true);
```

Comment: Can you show how you are loading content? If you aren't using a loader _and telling the grid about the loader_, then the grid will never know. Likewise if the data loads too quickly but then takes time to process before being rendered you also might not know, but more details are needed to help.